# Javacript click function for specific location with image

Tags: javascript, html, button

if you click on the tiger name button then the box image should be changed to the tiger image.  same for the next 2 buttons.
also, create 1 reset button to remove the box image and then display any default image in the box.
also, create 1 button to show the name of the image present in this image box. (result shown in an alert box.).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little more context would be desirable. Your question is a bit confused. Please post your code next time.
If I understood correctly, you can solve this with JavaScript:

Assuming you have your image tag and three buttons

```
<img id="tigerImage" alt="this is the tigers name" src="/assets/images/placeholder.jpg">
<button onclick="setImage()">Set Image</button>
<button onclick="resetImage()">Reset Image</button>
<button onclick="showName()">Show Name</button>
```

The id is important, you can address it with JS:

Vanilla JS:

```
function setImage() {
 document.getElementById("tigerImage").src="/assets/images/tiger.jpg";
}
function resetImage() {
 document.getElementById("tigerImage").src="/assets/images/placeholder.jpg";
}
function showName() {
    var imageName = document.getElementById("tigerImage").alt;
    alert(imageName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you "Fabio Thoma", this was the exact what I was trying to achieve. Thank you